# Can't get Grunt `watch` task to run?

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs, watch

Below is my Grunt file. My `watch:news` command doesn't appear to work and I'm not sure why.

When I run in verbose mode I can see that all the NPM modules are loaded without an issue, and it verifies that the `watch:news` task is running as it should be but then it just doesn't pick up that any changes have occurred?

I'm sure it's probably a typo or some small/easily fixable issue, I just can't spot it?

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    /*
        Grunt installation:
        -------------------
            npm install -g grunt-cli
            npm install -g grunt-init
            npm init (creates a `package.json` file)

        Project Dependencies:
        ---------------------
            npm install grunt --save-dev
            npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
            npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev
            npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
            npm install grunt-contrib-requirejs --save-dev
            npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev
            npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin --save-dev

        Example Usage:
        --------------
            grunt -v
            grunt release -v
    */

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Store your Package file so you can reference its specific data whenever necessary
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        dir: {
            static: './tabloid/webapp/static/',
            static_js: '<%= dir.static %>' + 'js/',
            static_sass: '<%= dir.static %>' + 'sass/',
            static_css: '<%= dir.static %>' + 'stylesheets/',
            static_img: '<%= dir.static %>' + 'img/'
        },

        jshint: {
            files: ['<%= dir.static %>**/*.js',
                    '!<%= dir.static_js %>jasmine/lib/**/*.js', 
                    '!<%= dir.static_js %>build.js', 
                    '!<%= dir.static_js %>compiled/**/*.js', 
                    '!<%= dir.static_js %>locator/**/*.js', 
                    '!<%= dir.static_js %>msie/**/*.js', 
                    '!<%= dir.static_js %>vendor/**/*.js'], 
            options: {
                curly:      true,
                eqeqeq:     true,
                immed:      true,
                latedef:    true,
                noarg:      true,
                sub:        true,
                undef:      true,
                boss:       true,
                eqnull:     true,
                browser:    true,
                multistr:   true,
                newcap:     false,

                globals: {
                    // AMD
                    module:       true,
                    require:      true,
                    requirejs:    true,
                    define:       true,

                    // Environments
                    console:      true,

                    // General Purpose Libraries
                    $:            true,
                    jQuery:       true,
                    EventEmitter: true,

                    // Testing
                    sinon:        true,
                    describe:     true,
                    it:           true,
                    expect:       true,
                    beforeEach:   true,
                    afterEach:    true
                }
            }
        },

        requirejs: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    baseUrl: '<%= dir.static_js %>',
                    paths: {
                        'jquery-1': 'vendor/jquery-1/jquery.min',
                        'jquery': 'vendor/jquery-2/jquery.min',
                        'domReady': 'vendor/require/domReady',
                        'translation': 'module/translations/news'
                    },
                    exclude: ['config', 'jquery' ],
                    name: 'define',
                    out: '<%= dir.static_js %>compiled/all.js',
                    fileExclusionRegExp: /^\.|node_modules|Gruntfile|\.md|package.json/
                }
            }
        },

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed',
                    require: ['<%= dir.static_sass %>helpers/url64.rb']
                },
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= dir.static_sass %>',
                src: ['*.scss', '!_*.scss'],
                dest: '<%= dir.static_css %>',
                ext: '.css'
            },
            dev: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded',
                    debugInfo: true,
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    require: ['<%= dir.static_sass %>helpers/url64.rb']
                },
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= dir.static_sass %>',
                src: ['*.scss', '!_*.scss'],
                dest: '<%= dir.static_css %>',
                ext: '.css'
            },
            news: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded',
                    debugInfo: true,
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    require: ['<%= dir.static_sass %>helpers/url64.rb']
                },
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= dir.static_sass %>/services/news/',
                src: ['*.scss'],
                dest: '<%= dir.static_css %>/services/news/',
                ext: '.css'
            }
        },

        // `optimizationLevel` is only applied to PNG files (not JPG)
        imagemin: {
            png: {
                options: {
                    optimizationLevel: 7
                },
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= dir.static %>img/',
                        src: ['**/*.png'],
                        dest: '<%= dir.static %>img/',
                        ext: '.png'
                    }
                ]
            },
            jpg: {
                options: {
                    progressive: true
                },
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= dir.static %>img/',
                        src: ['**/*.jpg'],
                        dest: '<%= dir.static %>img/',
                        ext: '.jpg'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        // Run: `grunt watch -v` from command line for this section to take effect
        // The -v flag is for 'verbose' mode, this means you can see the Sass files being compiled along with other important information
        watch: {
            all: {
                files: ['<%= jshint.files %>', '<%= sass.dev.src %>'],
                tasks: ['default']
            },
            news: {
                files: ['<%= sass.news.src %>'],
                tasks: ['news']
            }
        }

    });

    // Load NPM Tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');

    // Default Task
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'sass:dev']);

    // News Task
    grunt.registerTask('news', ['sass:news']);

    // Release Task
    grunt.registerTask('release', ['jshint', 'requirejs', 'sass:dist', 'imagemin']);

};
```

Comment: The only thing I can see is that in `sass:news` your `cwd` and `dest` options have an unneeded forward slash in them: `<%= dir.static_sass %>*/*services/news/`. I don't think that would cause a problem but it doesn't hurt to get rid of them, worth a try I think.

Comment: It may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577905/grunt-watch-task-block-the-command-line

Comment: What versions are you using of grunt-contrib-watch and grunt-contrib-sass?

Comment: "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.3.0"

Comment: "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.3.1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the problem was to do with watching `<%= sass.news.src %>` which doesn't work as we're using Grunt's expanded directory globbing.

The solution was to directly reference the folder I wanted to watch: `<%= dir.static_sass %>**/*.scss'`